# Calling the windows form from another project with the same values

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I open a form and initialize a function in that form. A progress bar is running. Then i hide the form with the same function. Now I need to show the window from another project with the same progress bar values. Is it possible to call the same form with out new keyword?

Note: My function which is used to hide the form is in VB.NET and function which is going to show the form is in C#.net

Here my code VB.NET (function going to hide the window)

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click

Dim objUpload As New UploadingList
objUpload.Show()
objUpload.Hide()
objUpload.UploadFiles()

End Sub
```

This uploadfiles() function initialize the progress bar and  uploading the files.
so if i need to show the window from  C# project, how can i do? if i create a new project, the progressbar values also get to default. Any solutions to this problem?

```
private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ICloudProvider.UploadingList objUpload = new ICloudProvider.UploadingList();
            objUpload.Show();
        }
```

If i follow the above function in C# all the control get to its default value. So there is no progress in progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public shared variable on the form to store a reference to the instance created in the VB program.

The form would have the following line:

```
Public Shared Instance as UploadingList
```

When you create the form, you need to set this variable:

```
Dim objUpload As New UploadingList
UploadingList.Instance = objUpload
objUpload.Show()
objUpload.Hide()
objUpload.UploadFiles()
```

Now from your C# program, instead of creating a new instance of the form, you would simply use the existing one:

```
private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ICloudProvider.UploadingList objUpload = ICloudProvider.UploadingList.Instance;
  if(objUpload!=null)
  {
    objUpload.Show();
  }
}
```

Remember to set the Instance variable to null (nothing in VB) when the form is closed.

Comment: Thanks dude. But already i solved this by the same way you told. Thank you very much.